# How to make visible shares only for specified users

Tags: permissions, samba, sharing

I have a Samba share with Windows groups access premission. I wanna to make all shares wisible only for specified in "valid users" groups. Now I have a $ shared directories that makes files unvisible for everyone(ofcourse access to r+w have only specified user groups).

So, my question is, How can I make a visible shares only for specified users groups. I need to make a list of accessible shres for user convenience.

**############SOLUTION:**

```
access based share enum = Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the `$` in a share name is to make it invisible, what you are  looking for is a "Mapped Drive", which could be done in one of these two ways

If the clients are in a domain environment you would set up a GPO (group policy object) that applies to specific groups, [This link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2009/01/07/using-group-policy-preferences-to-map-drives-based-on-group-membership/) should help

If the clients aren't in a domain environment you will need to write a simple script that the users click every day (or when they can't access it) you can see examples [at this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563028/script-to-map-network-drive)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I already done a mapped drives using GPO. So, I have a list of mapped drives, but I wanna to make a list of shares that user can access without mapping. It's very same to home dir's (cause users see only themself homedirs), but for usergroup's.
P.S.
I have a stuck of Kerberos, Winbind, Samba, AD, GPO

Comment: Sorry im not understanding ? You have a bunch of shares a user can access but you don't want to want to map them ? Can't you just send an email with hyper links that they can open (most desktop based based clients should follow them) ? Or are you trying to get a list of shares each user can access for some sort of report ?

Comment: No, I have already maped shares using GPO by usergroups and also I want to make visible shares only for users that have group access to this drives on the server path. Like a \\smb\bunch_of_visible_shares_for_specific_group. Not as map or list, but as map and list. And of course it's not have a big sense, but this is a very helpfull for users and especially for administrators.
Thank you for reply

Comment: As far as im aware anything ending with $ will be hidden over the SMB protocol, so you cant do \\smb\list_of_shares, I would just send an email with hyper links in it like \\smb\Share1$ \\smb\Share2$, \\smb\Share3 or an internal web page with links (but this would require addons to open them)

Comment: This feature already made in samba home folders. If you have no permissions to folder, than you dindn't see it. So I think to make something out of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
access based share enum = Yes
```

This directive will be make Share invisible to non permitted users and groups
 You can specifi users and groups in

```
valid users = "+DOMAIN\group"
```

directive